# How to overwrite JPA entity's @Table.catalog value?

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, eclipselink

When I use IntelliJ to generate a persistence mapping from exisitng database schema it puts a `catalog` value as part of `@Table` annotation. Unfortunately names of database instances have names of dev/test/prod environemnts in them and while I can overwrite the connection string with a map passed to `EntityManagerFactory` I still get `Invalid object name 'BAR_DEV.dbo.FOO'` when executing a query against `BAR_TEST` instance.

Can I dynamically overwrite the `catalog` value at runtime without doing global search and replace to remove it manually after entity generation?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO", schema = "dbo", catalog = "BAR_DEV")
public class Foo{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: or use orm.xml, with one value for dev, one for test and one for prod.

Comment: i'm afraid you are out of luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879607/change-table-name-of-an-entity-on-runtime

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible directly with standard JPA.

However, a solution I used in my project was to define **multiple persistence units**, each for a particular environment. You may overwrite any database mapping in an orm.xml file, or even set default catalog or schema for all entities. Next step is to dynamically retrieve proper `EntityManager` - if you are using Java EE, I recomment injecting using `@Inject` and creating a producer, which returns particular EM for specified environment.

Answer (score 0):

Non portable, Eclipselink only `org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicHelper.SessionCustomizer` can replace many defaults at runtime.

EDIT: I haven't ready code for You. I use this way

```
    public void customize(Session session) throws SQLException {
        ...
    for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : session.getDescriptors().values()) {

                if (!descriptor.getTables().isEmpty() && descriptor.getAlias().equalsIgnoreCase(descriptor.getTableName())) {
            tableName = TABLE_PREFIX + clazz.getSimpleName();
  descriptor.setTableName(tableName);
    }
    }
```