# Replacing static String in @Table annotation with external config YAML file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to use **two** different schemas in one java app. For now I'm setting the value with static text:

```
@Table(name = "jhi_user", catalog = "some_catalog")
@Table(name = "jhi_persistent_audit_event", catalog = "some_other_catalog")
```

I want to read those values from class marked with `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation but I don't have any ideas how to do it correctly.

I've tried to create enum with static subclass, but it only works with constant values.

```
public enum MyData {
    DB1(Constants.DB1),
    DB2(Constants.DB2);


    public static class Constants {
        public static final String DB1 = ApplicationProperties.getDb1(); //<--- : attribute value must be constant
        public static final String DB2 = "db2";   //<----- works 
    }
}
```

Is it any way to change database catalog for different classes *without* compiling the code? I suppose, I can set it to blank and then change them with reflection, is there a better way?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880200/5334060

Comment: What would be an **internal** config YAML file?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Alternatives to investigate. [1] You can override any JPA annotation by supplying an orm.xml file (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html). Not sure if this orm.xml could have dynamic attributes via, for example, environment vars. If not swap in at build time or externalize the orm.xml per environment???  [2] Work with mutiple  spring managed datasources???. The catalog(s) can be set dynamically using Spring config at runtime.

Comment: Could also externalise the orm.xml so can differ for each environment: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-use-external-xml-mappings-files-outside-of-jar-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I was inaccurate - I meant project's file. To be precise - I don't want to change any setting in the runtime. I need to set them only once - when my application starts.

Comment: JPA defines `orm.xml` for that very purpose ... a dumb idea is to hardcode schema info in annotations (especially when needing to change deployment). But then this is defined in any decent JPA docs