# How can I use a different table for each phase when using JPA in Spring?

Tags: spring

When using JPA in Spring, I want to use a different table for each phase.
In the example below, I would like to use "this-is-dev", "this-is-prod" table for each phase.
All columns in the table and JPA repository methods are same.
Is there a good way?

```
@Entity
@Table("this-is-dev") // for dev
// @Table("this-is-prod") //for prod
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // ... same columns
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
    // ... same methods
}
```

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {
    private final TestRepository repository;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work with annotations, since `@Table` annotations are not from Spring (they are from jpa) and thus you wont be able to conditionalize them. Also kind of duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879607/change-table-name-of-an-entity-on-runtime

Comment: I would rather use different database instances for the development phases. This is how it is usually done.

Comment: Can you show me example?

Comment: It rather fundamental question, why you will have different DB schema for Prod and Non-prod env

Comment: Dev and prod have different data.
I want to separate them

Comment: Of course data will be different. Having separate database schema or instance is the best solution.