# How can I set Datasource when I'm creating Hibernate SessionFactory?

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I'm creating SessionFactory and I have my datasource as object in code where I'm creating SessionFactory, but i cannot set datasource to Hibernate Configuration object. So how can I set my datasource to my SessionFactory?

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
configuration.setProperties(properties);
configuration.setProperty("packagesToScan", "com.my.app");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24175307/642706 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/884154/642706

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To supply JDBC connections to Session, you need an implementation of [ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html).

By default, Hibernate uses `DatasourceConnectionProvider` which obtains a `DataSource` instance from JNDI.

To use a custom `DataSource` instance, use `InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider` and inject the `DataSource` instance into it.

There is TODO note on [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/connection/InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.html)

> NOTE :
>   setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)
>   must be called prior to
>   configure(java.util.Properties).
>
> TODO : could not find where
>   setDataSource is actually called.
>   Can't this just be passed in to
>   configure???

As per the note, call `setDataSource()` method from `configure()` method.

```
public class CustomConnectionProvider extends InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider {
    @Override
    public void configure(Properties props) throws HibernateException {
        org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate( dataSource, props );
        setDataSource(dataSource);

        super.configure(props);
    }
}
```

You can also extend [UserSuppliedConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/connection/UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.html).

According to the contract of ConnectionProvider

> Implementors should provide a public
>   default constructor.

Hibernate will invoke this constructor if custom ConnectionProvider is set through Configuration instance.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put( Environment.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.class.getName() );
cfg.addProperties(props);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you happen to have your `DataSource` stored in JNDI, then simply use:

```
configuration.setProperty(
    "hibernate.connection.datasource",
    "java:comp/env/jdbc/yourDataSource");
```

But if you use a custom data source provider like Apache DBCP or BoneCP and **you don't want to use a dependency injection framework like Spring**, then you may inject it on the `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` before creating the `SessionFactory`:

```
//retrieve your DataSource
DataSource dataSource = ...;
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .configure();
//create the SessionFactory from configuration
SessionFactory sf = configuration
    .buildSessionFactory(
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            //here you apply the custom dataSource
            .applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource)
            .build());
```

Note that if you use this approach, you don't need to put the connection parameters in your hibernate.cfg.xml anymore. Here's an example of a compatible hibernate.cfg.xml file when using approach from above:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <!-- your mappings to classes go here -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Code above tested on Hibernate 4.3.

Comment: @PeterRader that's what I'm using: `.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource)`

Answer (score 4):

Luiggi Mendoza's answer is why my search sent me here, but I figure I should give my version because I spent quite some time looking around for how to do this - it sets it up with the Spring in-memory database for testing, a SessionContext and the hbm.xml in case you're not using annotations:

```
/**
 * Instantiates a H2 embedded database and the Hibernate session.
 */
public abstract class HibernateTestBase {

    private static EmbeddedDatabase dataSource;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
                setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).
                addScript("file:SQLResources/schema-1.1.sql").
                addScript("file:SQLResources/schema-1.2.sql").
                build();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addResource("hibernate-mappings/Cat.hbm.xml");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class",
                "org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder =
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySetting(Environment.DATASOURCE, dataSource);
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
                serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
        if (dataSource != null) {
            dataSource.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Before
    public final void startTransaction() {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public final void rollBack() {
        session.flush();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        transaction.rollback();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

}
```

and you'll need these:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.184</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your datasource is bounded at the JNDI tree:

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
```

Otherwise, if you have a DataSource object in code, which you want to use:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(conn);
```

I would recommend the first one, to let Hibernate handle the connection lifecycle as needed. At the second approach, make sure that you close the connection when it's no longer needed.

Comment: how can I add datasource to JNDI programmatically?

Comment: Are you working in a JEE enviroment? If yes, it would be better to set it up at the JEE container, and let it handle the creation and binding of the datasource at starting.

Comment: But I have 1 datasource per customer, and datasources are loaded in application startup, so I have to do this inside code. Every customer has own sessionfactory, because every customer has own database.

Comment: The JEE containers can handle multiple datasources with different JNDI names. When they are all available, you would need only use the distinctive JNDI name to select the desired one. Anyway, as said in my answer, if you really need to set the connection programatically, you can do it.

Comment: apparently I cannot add datasources to JNDI on tomcat, because its read only. Is there any other way to set datasource than JNDI ?

Comment: @newbie, check the @becomputer06 answer, maybe there you find your solution

Comment: better use `Environment.DATASOURCE` than "hibernate.connection.datasource"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. The Hibernate API will let you configure the JDBC properties so that it can manage the connections itself, or you can give it a JNDI DataSource location so it can go and fetch it, but I don't think you can *give* it a DataSource.

On the off-chance that you're using Spring, it's easier - use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to configure Hibernate, and inject your DataSource into that. Spring performs the necessary magic in the background.

Comment: do you have any links to example configurations?

Comment: @newbie: You mean like the documentation? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: I meant how can I use LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: @newbie: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring framework, then use LocalSessionFactoryBean for injecting your data source to Hibernate SessionFactory.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="YourClass"
        class="com.YourClass.
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="DbSessionFactory" />
        </property>     
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/yourdb</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>

    <bean id="DbSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>     
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>conf/hibernate/UserMapping.hbm.xml</value>               
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect </prop>      
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"> true </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've implemented a class with `javax.sql.DataSource`, Hibernate's `DataSource` can be set by configuring properties.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
public class HibernateDataSource implements DataSource {
    ...
}


import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
public class MyHibernateCfg {
    public void initialize() {
        HibernateDataSource myDataSource = new HibernateDataSource();
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        // this is how to configure hibernate datasource
        cfg.getProperties().put(Environment.DATASOURCE, myDataSource);
        ...
    }
}


import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
public class TableClass {
    public void initialize() {
        MyHibernateCfg cfg = new MyHibernateCfg();
        Configuration conf = cfg.getCfg();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session sessionFactory.openSession();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to create EntityManagerFactory instance at the configuration class.

If it is required to set another DataSource, than it is possible to update it with entity manager factory instance at runtime:

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService
{
....
    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf;
....
    public void replaceDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
....
}
```

It works with Hibernate 5.2.9 Final.