# How to create SessionFactory bean when datasource is defined but not xml but by configuration bean

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate 5.4

The dialect is known, I need to implement the following method :

```
@Bean
public org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    // hibernate.dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating one via a Configuration would work for you, as descibed here:

[Create Sessionfactory in Hibernate](https://www.mysoftkey.com/hibernate/how-to-create-sessionfactory-in-hibernate/)

> Configuration cfg = new Configuration()...

> .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "myuser");
> .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "mypassword")
> .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_example")

> SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

Or you choose to use the Spring LocalSessionFactory-Class like so:

```
lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean()  [from hib5-package]
lsfb.setDataSource( yourDS );
return lsfb.getObject();
```

Setting the Datasource this might help:
[Luiggi Mendoza on SO (How can I set Datasource when I'm creating Hibernate SessionFactory?
)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281186/9991282)

> But if you use a custom data source provider like Apache DBCP or BoneCP and you don't want to use a dependency injection framework like Spring, then you may inject it on the StandardServiceRegistryBuilder before creating the SessionFactory...